# Openerp Browser session logout

Tags: javascript, session, logout, odoo

I am using openerp web and server 5.15. Is there an way to kill the session of user when he/she closed the browser window?

If not, then is there any Javascript way then I can implement the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this has to do more with [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) (the Web Framework used in OpenERP) than with OpenERP itself. Try looking at this lines in `openerp-web.cfg`:

```
tools.sessions.on = True
tools.sessions.persistent = False
```